# Не удалось получить список каталогов filezilla

Tags: sftp

Я подключаюсь к своему серверу через FileZilla по протоколу SFTP, но при попытке скачать резервные копии на сервер, у меня при извлечении некоторых файлов выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
Команда:    cd "20-imap.ini"
Ошибка: Directory /etc/php5/mods-available/imap.ini: no such file or 
directory
Ошибка: Не удалось получить список каталогов
Статус: Получение списка каталогов "/etc/php5/conf.d/20-gd.ini"...
Команда:    cd "/etc/php5/conf.d"
Ответ:  New directory is: "/etc/php5/conf.d"
Команда:    cd "20-gd.ini"
Ошибка: Directory /etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini: no such file or directory
Ошибка: Не удалось получить список каталогов
```

а некоторые файлы извлекаются успешно:

```
Статус: Получение списка каталогов "/proc/vz/vzaquota"...
Статус: Listing directory /proc/vz/vzaquota
Статус: Список каталогов "/proc/vz/vzaquota" извлечен
```

Что я делаю не так? Почему нет доступа к этим каталогам?

Comment: что вы пытаетесь сделать ? вы пытаетесь закачать на сервер или скачать с сервера?

Comment: Пытаюсь к себе на сервер скачать бэкап через протокол SFTP... И некоторые файлы выдают ошибку: Не удалось получить список каталогов

Comment: какого формата файлы которые не закачиваются ?

Comment: Ну наверное в формате zip

Comment: попробуйте разархивировать и залить, возможно у вас ограничение по обьёму файлов, не уверен что поможет но всё же вам придётся после загруски разпаковывать

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую